# Trouble adding more search variables in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parameters, isset

I am trying to add onto a mysql search array $. The actual script runs fine when it is like below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT item, IdPhotos FROM purchases WHERE username = ? AND sname = ?';
$params = array( $login, $sname );

if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
  $sql .= " AND cusername LIKE ?";
  $params []= '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';
}
```

However, I am trying to add two more search variables. However, my script is telling me that there is an unknown error on line 14. What am I doing wrong?

```
   ...
    if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
      $sql .= " AND (cusername LIKE ? OR myname LIKE ? OR item LIKE ?)";
 //line 14 below 
      $params []= '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';                                                        
    }
```

Comment: If you want help when receiving errors, you sort of need to post those errors too. Right off the bat though, in the if (isset) portion, you are adding three parameters with the ? and only adding a single item into the $params array. You have to have in index in the params for every ? index you have.

Comment: its an a issue with `$params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the same amount of parameters as you are adding parameter symbols.

This is your fix, albeit it sloppy. You should convert to named parameters in this case.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
    $sql .= " AND (cusername LIKE ? OR myname LIKE ? OR item LIKE ?)";

    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';                                                        
    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';   
    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';   
}
```

Using named parameters would look like this:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
    $sql .= " AND (cusername LIKE :name OR myname LIKE :name OR item LIKE :name)";

    $params[':name'] = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';                                            
}
```

This way it will auto replace every instance of the named parameter.